# Merging empty header columns in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to merge empty header columns for the heading of dataframe.

I used Multiindex to get text up over header columns. Using Following code:

```
sub_df_2.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples ( zip([Short_Mutation_Operator_Name, '', '', '', '', '' ,''], sub_df_2.columns))
```

I want a "merge cell" effect like in excel. How do I code that?

[image: I want merge cell effect]

This is the desired result.
Also is there any way to make text central? Centre text is optional.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't do that by default if the first layer of the multiindex is the same? Have you tried e.g. `zip([Short_Mutation_Operator_Name] * 7, sub_df_2.columns)` ?

Comment: nope now all header columns have same string.